# Number theory textbook exercise $11^{n+2} + 12^{2n + 1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I have been stuck on proving the equation $11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $133$ for all positive counting integers $N$. The proof should ideally use induction and I'm not sure how to proceed through the inductive step

It's asking something like this problem: [Show that this expression is divisible by $133$ [more info in desc.]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634939/show-that-this-expression-is-divisible-by-133-more-info-in-desc)

but I'm not sure how the modulo are derived equal and I would like to use induction.

Comment: You are not asking the same question. The link you gave has a different question. Further, the statement you wrote is incorrect too. It is not divisible if you take n=1 (I don't know about the rest though!).

Comment: I apologize I made a couple edits to clarify and corrected to the right question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction Step:

$11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1} = 133*k$

and

$11^{(n+1)+2} + 12^{2(n+1) + 1} =$

$11^{(n+2)+1} + 12^{(2n+1) + 2}=$

$11^{n+2}*11 + 12^{2n+1}*144 =$

$11^{n+2}+ 12^{2n+1}*11 + 12^{2n+1}*133 =$

$(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1})*11 + 12^{2n+1}*133 =$

$[133*k]*11 + 12^{2n+1}*133 = $

$133 \times (11k + 12^{2n+1})$.

....

If you want to be slick an look like a magician take the above and do it backwards:

$11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1} = 133*k$

$(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1})11 = 133*(11k)$

$11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+1}*11 = 133*(11k)$

$11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+1}*11 + 12^{2n+1}*133 = 133*(11k) + 133*12^{2n+1}$

$11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+1}(11 + 133) = 133(11k + 12^{2n+1})$

$11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+1}*144 = 133(11k + 12^{2n+1})$

$11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+1}*12^2 = 11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+3} = 133(11k + 12^{2n+1})$

$11^{(n+2) + 1} + 12^{2(n+1) + 1} = 133(11k + 12^{2n+1})$

Answer (score 2):

The induction step $n \rightarrow n+1$ without modular arithmetic may look as follows:

- Induction hypothesis (IH): $133 | (11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}) \Leftrightarrow 11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1} = 133 \cdot k$ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}$
- Induction step:
  $$11^{n+3} + 12^{2n+3} = 11\cdot 11^{n+2} + 144\cdot 12^{2n+1}= 11\cdot 11^{n+2} + (133+11)\cdot 12^{2n+1} $$ $$= 133\cdot 12^{2n+1} + 11(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}) \stackrel{IH}{=} 133\cdot 12^{2n+1} + 133 \cdot k$$

Answer (score 2):

Without induction, consider mod $133$:
$$\begin{align}11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}&\equiv 121\cdot 11^{n} + 12\cdot 144^{n}\equiv \\
&\equiv (-12)\cdot 11^n+12\cdot 11^n\\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{133}.\end{align}$$

Comment: deserves an upvote!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with congruence. How did you go from the second congruence to the the third one?

Comment: $121\equiv 133-12\equiv -12 \pmod{133}$ and $144\equiv 133+11\equiv 11 \pmod{133}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $11\cdot 12 =132 \equiv -1 \pmod {133}$.  They also use $144 \equiv 11 \pmod {133}$.  That should get you through the chain in the linked question.

To do an inductive proof, note that for $n=1$ we have $11^3+12^3=3059 \equiv 0 \pmod {133}$.  Then assume it is true for $k$, and we have 
$$11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1}\equiv 0 \pmod {133}\\
11^{k+3}+12^{2k+3}=11\cdot 11^{k+2}+144\cdot 12^{2k+1}\\\equiv 11\cdot(11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1})\equiv 0 \pmod {133}$$

Answer (score 0):

Like

[Prove by induction that $3^{3n+1} + 2^{n+1}$ is divisible by 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176215/prove-by-induction-that-33n1-2n1-is-divisible-by-5/1176218#1176218)

or

[Proving that $64$ divides $3^{2n+2}+56n+55$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488976/proving-that-64-divides-32n256n55-by-induction/1489018#1489018),

If $P(m)=11^{m+2}+12^{2m+1}$

$$P(n+1)-11P(n)=12^{2n+1}(12^2-11)$$ which is divisible by $133$

Or $P(m+1)-12^2P(m)=11^{n+2}(11-12^2)$ which is divisible by $133$

In either case,

$133|P(n+1)\iff133|P(n)$ as $(11,133)=(12,133)=1$